# Import Java source code as library in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I've just started Android development coming from a strong web and iOS development background. One thing I don't really understand is how to best import third party open source projects in my source.

In web development most projects has a `bower` package and in `iOS` most open source projects has a podspec that makes it really easy to import. But I don't see this as much in Java projects.

So, now I want to use [jess-anders/two-way-gridview](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). What would be the best way to get this into my own app. I would very much like to avoid having to mix the third party source code and res files with my own.

I use IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, then what you need is [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which is used for dependency management in Java projects.

You define your dependencies inside a **pom.xml** file. [Here](http://svn.codehaus.org/tynamo/trunk/tynamo-example-federatedaccounts/pom.xml) is an example of such pom file (see the < dependencies > tag ).

Generally, when you need to use a 3rd-party library, you look it up in the [Maven Central Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/), from which Maven looksup by default when you specify a dependency, and copy the < dependency > element into you pom.xml file.

NOTE: I don't know why, but right now the Maven site is down. You'll have to check back later. In the meantime try looking for some tutorials on google.

If you need to import libraries which aren't in the Maven Repo, then you need to go to File>Project Structure>Libraries and click on the '+' symbol and add your .jar files from the your filesystem.

[image]

You need to do this on every machine that needs to work on this project, and also include the jars in your final apk. I do not konw how to do the latter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question was more about how to import third party libraries that doesn't exists in the maven repo. Seems like many libraries does not.

Maybe what I'm looking for is to create a JAR?

Comment: @JohanNordberg, updated the answer, hope it's useful